# How to move and rotate custom marker in leaflet along the path it travels?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I am working on a project which uses leaflet. My goal is to move my custom icon marker along the path and i have achieve it using Leaflet.MovingMarker library. But the problem i am facing is that I dont know how to rotate the marker along the path. Please help me.

[image: This is what i try to achieve]

I want the head of the airplane to point towards the path it travels.

Note: I am doing my project in vanila JS. I am using the same example from Leaflet.MovingMarker with the custom marker.

Comment: The most easy way would be to use (Leaflet.PolylineDecorator)[https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator] but I don't think that it would work with the animation. You can look into the code how they have done the rotation along the line. The general rotation is done over [Leaflet.RotatedMarker](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker)

Comment: thanks for the reply but this solution doesnt help me with what i want to do...actually i want my marker to move and rotate according the path.. please help

Comment: Have you resolved this?